# Show '...' when text is longer that the area in textblock

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

Some days back i saw an example of what i need now but couldn't remind what was the way.

I want to show the text description in `TextBlock` and if the text is more that the size of text block, show the **...**

Comment: You're looking for the [TextTrimming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.texttrimming.aspx) property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code to achieve this,

```
 <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource someText}"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                Margin="10"/>
```

And possible values of TextTrimming are as below,

- None – no ellipsis, text is clipped  (the default)
- CharacterEllipsis – display as many characters as possible, followed
  by an ellipsis
- WordEllipsis – display as many words as possible, followed by an
  ellipsis

Comment: Plus the value [`Clip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.texttrimming.aspx) - "Introduced in Windows 8.1. Text is trimmed at a pixel level, visually clipping the excess glyphs".

Answer (score 1):

I know link only answer are frowned upon but

[TextBlock.TextTrimming Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.texttrimming.aspx)

```
<TextBlock 
  Name="myTextBlock" 
  Margin="20" Background="LightGoldenrodYellow" 
  TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap"
  FontSize="14">
  One<LineBreak/>
  two two<LineBreak/>
  Three Three Three<LineBreak/>
  four four four four<LineBreak/>
  Five Five Five Five Five<LineBreak/>
  six six six six six six<LineBreak/>
  Seven Seven Seven Seven Seven Seven Seven
</TextBlock>
```